# How to get $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, product, cart, magento-1

In my magento application created a phtml page in template/page/ folder..

Here displayed a products...Then there is a need for displaying

`$this->getAddToCartUrl($product)`

But it return null value...that means no value returned it.

How can i get it in my phtml page?

This is the html code:

```
<input id="url_<?php echo $_iterator;?>" name="url_$_iterator;" type="text" value="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try calling this instead:

```
$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product)
```

Comment: thanku so much....its working....

Answer (score 1):

Using the helper 'checkout/cart' with get link but it want solve the problem as you will run with similar issues with the price.

I think it is better to change if you can change the template type definition in your xml, something like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" template="your-template.phtml" name="your-name" as="your-name" />
```

Like that you will have in $this not only the link but the price with out calling the magento helper directly.